# Concluding that a sequence of integrals is not bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Using Riemann-Lebesgue's theorem we can show that for a function $f$ in $\mathcal C^1 ([0,\pi]) $, we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( n\int_0^\pi f(t) \cos nt \ dt \biggr) = 0$$
For each $n\in \mathbb N$, define $T_n:\mathcal C ([0,\pi]) \to \mathbb R$ as $ T_n(f) = n  {\int_0^\pi} \ f(t) \cos nt \ dt $. I was asked to show that $||T_n || \ge n/2$, which I did for $f(t)=\cos nt$.

Then I am asked to conclude that there exists $f \in C ([0,\pi])$ such that the sequence $\bigg( n\int_0^\pi f(t) \cos nt \ dt \biggr)_{n\in \mathbb N} $ is not limited.

I understand that somehow the existence of this function comes from the non-existance of a limit to the norm of the linear operator, but I am unable to prove it. My guess is that the proof employs the [Banach-Stenhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), but I couldn't find a  way to do so yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if such $f$ did not exist, what would Banach-Steinhaus say about the sequence of operators $T_n$?

Comment: You're right, should've thought of that.